# How do I make the image move with every frame of the video?

Tags: animation, video, 2d

I just want to make the image in the frame move with every frame of the video.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make an effort to describe the situation. Is the person moving the frame, and you want the superimposed image to track with the motion?

Comment: Note that you  don't need the color key at all, just do a plane track.